# Fetch a user from firebase through UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to delete a user from firebase through an admin panel, to delete a user, according to the documentation, this is how it is done

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

However, I am trying to delete the a user that is not the currentUser, is it possible to somehow fetch a user through its UID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a Firebase user to fetch or delete other arbitrary users.  That would be a massive security hole.

You will need to have a backend for this, and your client is going to have to instruct the backend to delete the user account using the Firebase Admin SDK to [manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).